# How to pre-load data to avoid multiple firebase reads in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Problem**: A specific component in my web app reads a large amount of data from Firebase Firestore every time a user navigates there. This causes hundreds of thousands of un-necessary reads to my Firestore db.

**Question**: How can I pre-load or "cache" Firestore data so the web app has it available **regardless** of when **any** user loads/visits the site?

**Additional Info**:

- The specific component loads all documents from a Firestore collection which contains around 850 documents. The data in this collection doesn't change much and specifically is a list of names that contain a sub-collection of cities. Each one of these city sub collections holds another collection of addresses that this person has lived at. This component uses the names in a dynamic search bar which is re-loaded each time the user goes to the component.
- This component also reads and displays the top `x` number of people who have the most addresses. This causes many more reads as I use the same function that gets all the people to read all people (then sort and return the top `x` number).
- Im using Angular 13 and my site is being hosted by Firebase. I'm not too familiar with web hosting in general, so I dont know the extent of what I can even "do".

**Attempted solutions**: I've considered having the web app read the collection on initial load, then populate with that data when the user loads the component. That would save some reads as the collection isnt read each time the user clicks on the specific component, but it still causes a ton of reads as the data is read every time the user refreshes / re-visits the site.

**Goal**: Overall, im trying to find a solution to reduce the number of reads on my Firestore db. I'm open to other solutions that may fix the problem, even if I have to re-think my approach or use a different resource.

**Code**:

firebase.service.ts:

```
export class FirebaseService {
  private peoplePath = '/people';
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  getAllPeople(): Observable<Person[]> {
    let colRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
    colRef = this.firestore.collection(this.peoplePath);
    return colRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as any;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
  }

  getPerson(personId: string) {
    let itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Person>;
    let path = this.peoplePath + "/" + personId;
    itemDoc = this.firestore.doc<Person>(path);
    return itemDoc.valueChanges();
  }

  getTopPeople(amount: number): Person[] {
    let topPeople: Person[] = [];
    this.getAllPeople().subscribe(aPeople => {
      let people = aPeople as Person[];
      people.sort((a,b) => (a.total_addresses < b.total_addresses) ? 1 : -1);
      let count = 0;
      for (let p of people) {
        topPeople.push(p);
        count++;
        if (count == amount) {
          break;
        }
      }
      return topPeople;
    });
    return topPeople;
  }
```

person-search.component.ts:

```
export class PersonSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  term: string;
  showSearch: boolean = false;
  numOfPeople: number = 20;
  numOfPeopleDisplay: number = 20;
  constructor(private fbService: FirebaseService) { }

  allPeople: Observable<Person[]> = this.fbService.getAllPeople();

  topPeople: Person[] = this.fbService.getTopPeople(20);

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  getPeople() {
    this.topPeople = this.fbService.getTopPeople(this.numOfPeople);
    this.numOfPeopleDisplay = this.numOfPeople;
  }
}
```

person-search.component.html:

```
<div>
    <input name="search"  type="text" (focus)="showSearch = true" placeholder="Search for people"  [(ngModel)]="term">
    <div class="personSearchResults" *ngIf="showSearch">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let person of allPeople | async | personfilter:term">
                    <td><a routerLink="/person-page/{{person.first_name}}_{{person.last_name}}">{{person.first_name}}</a></td>
                    <td><a routerLink="/person-page/{{person.first_name}}_{{person.last_name}}">{{person.last_name}}</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <span>Enter any number: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="numOfPeople"></span>
    <button (click)="getPeople()">Sort</button>
    <p>Top {{numOfPeopleDisplay}} people by number of addresses:</p>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Number of addresses</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let person of topPeople; let i=index;">
                <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
                <td><a routerLink="/person-page/{{person.first_name}}_{{person.last_name}}">{{person.first_name}} {{person.last_name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{person.total_addresses}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

If there is any additional information needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are Firestore's [data bundles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles), which (according to this page on [serving bundled Firestore content from a CDN](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles)):

> Cloud Firestore bundles allow you to assemble data bundles from common query results on the backend using the Firebase Admin SDK, and serve these pre-computed blobs cached on a CDN. This gives your users a much faster first load experience and reduces your Cloud Firestore query costs.

So:

1. Create a bundle with the docs you want to have in the cache
2. Store that bundle in a place that is cheaper to read from than Firestore's API.
3. Download the bundle and push it into the local cache of the client.
4. And then just use the normal API to read the documents, which is now all locally cached.

Comment: Regarding step 2, what would be a good place to store this bundle?

Comment: That depends on your criteria, but since cost is the main one here I'd say a place that is cheaper to read from than Firestore's API. Firebase Hosting or Cloud Storage come to mind, but honestly... there are plenty of options there.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I can write a separate program to create and store the bundle(s) on one of the services, then update my web app to read from that location instead?

Comment: Yes, that's steps 1 through 4 in my answer. Give it a try!

Comment: Is there any documentation on reading/loading the bundle from its URL in Cloud Storage? I cant seem to find documentation or example on how to do this in Angular/Typescript

Comment: That has little to do with Firestore, so I'd expect you get better results when searching for [downloading a file from a URL in JavaScript](https://www.google.com/search?q=downloading+a+file+from+a+URL+in+JavaScript).